# Filezilla not able to connect to sub domain

Tags: apache-http-server, amazon-web-services, filezilla

Hosting with AWS, using Apache webserver (using Webmin)

I am using Filezilla to connect to www.domain.com.

I am not able to connect to a subdomain, m.domain.com using filezilla. It always defaults back to the directories of www.domain.com

I am able to view the m.domain.com on the web browser. How do I set it up to connect to m.domain.com

Tried setting the default remote directory to - /var/www/vhosts/m.domain.com/public_html but it default back to domain directory.

I thought it was a dns issue but I am able to view m.domain.com in the browser.

Advice and help appreciated.

Thank you

Richard

Comment: Have you verified 1) which directory the m.domain.com serves files from and 2) if that directory is available via FTP (this access would be set in AWS)? HTTP access and FTP access are two separate things.

Comment: Many thanks for taking time to help. 

Right now the ftp access for www.domain.com is is http access, i believe. In the browser for m.domain.com, it serves the correct directory but not when i use filezilla for ftp.  Therefore, i believe i need to set up the ftp configuration for m.domain.com. How do I set the directory via FTP in AWS?